# How to make Ajax.request to work in localhost:50000

Tags: construct-2

Loading XML document only seems to work when the exported project is uploaded to web server?

How to make file request to work when running game in C2 dev.env. meaning localhost:50000

```
Ajax.request "xml/data.xml"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just needed to import xml file into C2 project using GUI, under Files folder, solved!!